# Total Calculation on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sum

I've a form template, and I'm looking on how I can add more fields to a product (sizes with dropbox quantity) and calculate the sum of all sizes to the total price calculation, the code is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
JotForm.setConditions([{"action":[{"field":"2","visibility":"Hide"}],"index":0,"link":"Any","priority":"0","terms":[{"field":"4","operator":"isEmpty","value":false},{"field":"5","operator":"isEmpty","value":false},{"field":"13","operator":"isEmpty","value":false},{"field":"9","operator":"isEmpty","value":false}],"type":"field"}]);

JotForm.init(function(){

  setTimeout(function() {
      $('input_13').hint('ex: myname@example.com');
   }, 20);
  productID = {"0":"input_3_1001","1"};
  paymentType = "product";
  JotForm.setCurrencyFormat('BRL',true);
  JotForm.totalCounter({"input_3_1001":{"price":"42","quantityField":"input_3_quantity_1001_0"}});
  JotForm.highlightInputs = false;
```

});

HTML

```
            <input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="input_3_1001" name="q3_input3[][id]" value="1001" />
        <label for="input_3_1001">
          Camisa Social Feminina Manga Curta
          <br>
          Branca/Detalhe Marinho (Panama)
          <span class="form-product-details">
            <b>
              R$
              <span id="input_3_1001_price">
                42.00
              </span>
            </b>
          </span>
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span class="form-sub-label-container">
          <select class="form-dropdown" name="q3_input3[special_1001][item_0]" id="input_3_quantity_1001_0">
            <option value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> 2 </option>
            <option value="3"> 3 </option>
            <option value="4"> 4 </option>
            <option value="5"> 5 </option>
            <option value="6"> 6 </option>
            <option value="7"> 7 </option>
            <option value="8"> 8 </option>
            <option value="9"> 9 </option>
            <option value="10"> 10 </option>
          </select>
          <label class="form-sub-label" for="input_3_quantity_1001_0"> GG </label>
        </span>
        <span class="form-sub-label-container">
          <select class="form-dropdown" name="q3_input3[special_1001][item_1]" id="input_3_custom_1001_1">
            <option value="1"> 1 </option>
            <option value="2"> 2 </option>
            <option value="3"> 3 </option>
            <option value="4"> 4 </option>
            <option value="5"> 5 </option>
            <option value="6"> 6 </option>
            <option value="7"> 7 </option>
            <option value="8"> 8 </option>
            <option value="9"> 9 </option>
            <option value="10"> 10 </option>
          </select>
          <label class="form-sub-label" for="input_3_custom_1001_1"> GG2 </label>
        </span>
      </span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I'm looking for a solution, I'm sorry that I do work with this like you, I'm only trying to fix this for my mother that don't have money enough to pay for anyone to do this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (I simplify it to simple Javascript only)

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var prices = {item1:5.5, item2:32, item3:11.2, item4:33.7};

function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    for (id in prices) {
        total += prices[id]*document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
}

</script>

<body>
<input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="product" value="1001" />
Camisa Social Feminina Manga Curta
<br>
Branca/Detalhe Marinho (Panama)
<b>
R$
<span id="total">
0.00
</span>
</b>
<br>
<br>

<select id="item1" onchange="getTotal()">
 <option>0<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>7<option>8<option>9<option>10</option>
</select>

<select id="item2" onchange="getTotal()">
 <option>0<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>7<option>8<option>9<option>10</option>
</select>

<select id="item3" onchange="getTotal()">
 <option>0<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>7<option>8<option>9<option>10</option>
</select>

<select id="item4" onchange="getTotal()">
 <option>0<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>7<option>8<option>9<option>10</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```